# Crossrider chrome extension: set manifest.json

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, crossrider

I'd like to make a chrome extension in [crossrider.com](http://www.crossrider.com). The extension should have a shared storage which is accessible from every pages. Chrome extension storage seemed to be useful for this purpose. But I can't find manifest.json to start using extension storage. Anyone help me to find manifest.json.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you only want to make a Chrome extension, don't use Crossrider, that is an unnecessary and limiting abstraction layer. If you want to use Crossrider, read its documentation, there are two supported storage APIs in Crossrider..

Comment: I am developing cross-browser extension so crossrider was the best option. I will have a look at the crossrider storage api. Thank you.